# Renormalization of two-sublattice tight-binding Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, renormalization, hamiltonian, tight-binding

I have a generic tight-binding Hamiltonian of the form
$$H=\sum_n A c_n^\dagger d_n+Bd_n^\dagger c_n +C c_{n+1}^\dagger d_n + D d_n^\dagger c_{n+1}$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are parameters (hopping amplitudes) and the system is a two-sublattice system, one sublattice for each of the operators $c$ and $d$. I would like to know what does a renormalization process look like if we want to effectively remove one sublattice (say the one corresponding to operators $d$) and get the effective hopping amplitudes only between sites of sublattice with operators $c$.

Thank you!

**Edit:**
A thought I had was calculating the Green's function
$$G(k, \omega)=(\omega-H(k))^{-1}$$
where $H(k)$ is the Bloch Hamiltonian. $G$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix of the form
$$G=\begin{bmatrix}
    G_{cc} & G_{cd} \\
    G_{dc} & G_{dd} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The $G_{cc}$ component is purely related to one sublattice of the initial model. Also for a Green's function of the generic schematic form $G=\frac{1}{\Sigma-\omega}$, $\Sigma$ is the physical energy of the system, which I was thinking in the case of $G_{cc}$ it can be interpreted as the effective energy of the sublattice corresponding to operators $c$. Is this correct? If so, how can we go from the effective energy to the effective Hamiltonian?